# Check applied to list is not the same as list of Check

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

My question is in two parts. First, I want to know why

```
Check[#, "Failed"] &@{0^0, 1^1}
```

evaluates to

```
{Indeterminate, 1}
```

while

```
{Check[0^0, "Failed"], Check[1^1, "Failed"]}
```

evaluates to

```
{"Failed", 1}
```

Then, I'd like to know if there is a way to make an expression of the first type (i.e. having `Check[#, "Failed"]` with an existing list "applied to it") evaluate to what I would call the "expected result" of

```
{"Failed", 1}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `Check[#, "Failed"] &` you are creating a pure [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), which by default does not hold its arguments in the way that [`Check`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) does.

So when you evaluate

```
Check[#, "Failed"] &@{0^0, 1^1}
```

the list `{0^0, 1^1}` evaluates **first** before even being fed to `Check`.  You could create a pure `Function` that *does* hold its arguments with something like

```
In[13]:= Function[x, Check[x, "Failed"], {HoldAll, Listable}]@{0^0, 1^1}

During evaluation of In[13]:= Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered.

Out[13]= {"Failed", 1}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because the key trick I was missing was the ability to "Hold" an expression. However, I actually waned the return to be Failed or not for each element in the list which I see I didn't make clear originally with &@ instead of &/@ syntax. The following works `Check[ReleaseHold[#], "Failed"] & /@ {0^0 // Hold, 1^1 // Hold}`

Comment: @Nic - see the update which uses the `Listable` attribute